# Access.mdb not retaining original structure when saved

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-access, microsoft-office-2013

Our Access database currently in the .accdb format (Office 2013) retains a particular structure, showing all the project information on the left hand side (a long list cascading down the screen). Once it's saved within Office 2016, it turns to the.mdb format and we can no longer see the project information to the left. How can this be corrected?

Answer (score 0):

First, [do not use *Excel*](https://www.lifewire.com/accdb-file-2619459) or tools other than *Access* (or LibreOffice *Base*) to open the file: "Microsoft Excel will import ACCDB files but **that data will then have to be saved in some other spreadsheet format**."

Second, when saving in *Access*, be sure to select the *Save as...* option and choose `Access Database (*.accdb)`, though that *should* be the default format for *Access* 2016.

[image]

Comment: I tried that but it still lost the original format with the information on the side..

Comment: If it's being saved as *.accdb* now, then perhaps the information on the sidebar is in a macro. Check that macros are allowed.